# Update of add-in with workflow fails

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, app

**Scenario:**

- A very simple app with a simple workflow (all it does is write to the workflow history)
- Upload the app to the app catalog and add to a site. Everything works fine, able to open the app
- Make a small change to the workflow (modify the text in workflow history) and update the version in AppManifest
- Upload the new version to the app catalog
- Try to update the app

**Result - update fails with the below error ...**

> *"Sorry, something went wrong with updating the app. Click to retry."*

**Stack is something like**

> *There was an error during the operation. Details: Scope '/SharePoint/default/7bb242e3-a61e-4644-b767-f9d218521c35/46e345a7-7e93-4872-a601-e346d7a45245/$Snapshot'
>   was not found. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId:
>   0b955381-f171-48a1-a825-71ca773df123. NodeId: xxxxxxxx. Scope:
>   /SharePoint/default/7bb242e3-a61e-4644-b767-f9d218521c35/46e345a7-7e93-4872-a601-e346d7a45245/$Snapshot.
>   Client ActivityId : 4a389047-d8f7-4a22-b9e8-95f6bb31c229.*

This only happens when there is a workflow in the app ...

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: you can try uninstalling the app, then later again package your app and push to App catalog and reinstall again